# Can't Pull Bar to Mount Storage

Tags: internal-storage, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-i7500

I don't know what's wrong with my phone. Things are breaking left and right ...

To mount the phone so I can access files on it (I don't have an SD card), I:

- Disable USB debugging
- Enable Mass Storage Mode
- Plug the phone in
- Go to the home screen
- Drag that bar down on the top of the screen
- Click on the USB item
- Click "Mount Storage"

Viola,  I can access my files. The problem now is that the bar at the top doesn't drag down. I fear that it's a hardware issue (is there some way to disable/enable it from the software side?)

Having said that, how can I now mount the storage to transfer files onto my computer? I have several (100ish) 1.5MB images I need to copy over.

I have a Samsung i7500g running Android 1.6.

I wrote my own app, which can trap events on the top bar part of the screen; it seems that it's only the home page bar that doesn't allow me to drag it down. Is there some setting I'm missing?

**Edit:** Even stranger, sometimes, the pull bar works perfectly.

Comment: When was the last time you switched the phone off? Have you tried rebooting it? That often sorts out a lot of these odd problems that crop  up when the phone's been running for quite a while, particularly with older Android versions like 1.6.

Comment: @GAThrawn I think it was rebooted recently. Someone sending  a text somehow enabled the bar. It's not my phone, so I'll check it and let you know tonight.

Comment: Try a different USB cable.  Some cheap cables can make the screen act strange when plugged in.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The cable seems okay. Restarted the phone and nothing happened. But my app, which runs full-screen, can handle click events for that high up; just the top bar doesn't work.

Comment: Check logs using `CatLog` app.. Try to pinpoint event exactly when you drag status bar...

Comment: And, apps can disable dragging.. For example, `Widget Locker` app allows users to do that..

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. I haven't installed any apps recently, so it can't be that.

Comment: @SachinShekhar CatLog doesn't do anything for me. I can see the "Texture" something input event not handled; no other information. (This is strangely inconsistent.)

Answer (score 1):

When you're done transferring these files, it is more important that you eject the device from the computer than it is for you to unmount the SD from the statusbar.

Once your computer says the device is ejected, the problem should be resolved after you unplug the phone--

If not-- you can transfer files via adb without 'mounting' the sdcard. 
In this case, you would not disable the debugging option (Which you don't really need to do in the first place, btw).

=D

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question. He can't pull down the notification bar.

Comment: His application very well could be the cause of the frozen bar. Who knows what could be the cause-?- Especially when he cannot get it to consistently fail. 

(Thus it very well could be a memory issue.)

 This is a potential solution. 
Unplugging the device from the USB should free up the bar again.

Comment: I'm not aware of any api that could lock the bar. Memory issue? What does ram have to do with this? He can't mount it in the first place, so he can't unmount it.

Comment: There isn't one. But if we were all aware of every bug in existence, we'd have exterminated them all by now. 

Ahm, I was thinking he said the screen was *frozen*- you're right, it has nothing to do with RAM. 

But he said he could mount it-- 
See^ "Voila" just after the bullets.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use an app like [Auto Mount Your SD Card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.automount), which would automatically switch to UMS (USB mass storage) mode when your device gets connected to a computer via USB. If you still want to manually decide, this seems to be provided by [MountUSB Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.abraxas.mountusb.donate) (which is not free, but costs ~EUR 1).

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause would be using a custom launcher (ADW, Go Launcher, Apex, Nova, Launcher Pro, etc..). Some of these launchers allow you to hide the status bar at the top, and trigger it with actions like double tapping the home screen, swiping up or down, swiping with two fingers, etc..

What might be happening is that you are unintentionally triggering the show/hide status bar. When hidden, you can no longer pull it down.

If you are using a custom launcher, go to the launcher settings, there you will find an option that allows you to customize behavior .

I can also tell you if the issue is with the status bar, it is most definitely not a hardware issue.

Comment: I'm not using a custom launcher. Thanks for coming out though :)